# RPC deployment Guideline

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, kusama, rpc

I have a question in regard to RPC node for Polkadot or Substrate.

RPC node configuration - I don't see too many information about this. Is there public information on how to setup a RPC, if there isn't, I am willing to do that if someone is willing to help me to understand how to setup.

If there are any more information on how to setup RPC node, and back to Polkadot.JS. please don't hesitate to contact me and help me with me. Much appreciate.

Comment: Hi @stken99, welcome to the community! You may get a better response limiting your post to one question. If you have multiple questions, consider creating multiple posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this tutorial

https://github.com/CocDap/VBI-Octopus-2/tree/assignment-3

Step by step for RPC configuration:

1. Declare your runtime api in your specific pallet: https://github.com/CocDap/VBI-Octopus-2/blob/assignment-3/pallets/template/rpc/runtime-api/src/lib.rs#L7
2. Declare your rpc method and implement runtime api trait
   https://github.com/CocDap/VBI-Octopus-2/blob/assignment-3/pallets/template/rpc/src/lib.rs#L37
3. Declare helper function in your pallet: https://github.com/CocDap/VBI-Octopus-2/blob/assignment-3/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L211
4. Define your runtime api in runtime/src/lib.rs: https://github.com/CocDap/VBI-Octopus-2/blob/assignment-3/runtime/src/lib.rs#L441
5. Add your custom rpc in node/src/rpc.rs: https://github.com/CocDap/VBI-Octopus-2/blob/assignment-3/node/src/rpc.rs#L36

And how you query value through RPC

```
curl http://localhost:9933 -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" -d   '{
     "jsonrpc":"2.0",
      "id":1,
      "method":"<your rpc method",
      "params": []
    }'
```

More materials from Substrate:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/transaction-payment/rpc

https://substrate.recipes/custom-rpc.html ( This is old version, But good info for you)